# How to get Asp.Net GridView control ID in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, clientid

I did try searching and I tried all the solution provided and I still cannot get this to work, the javascript is returning null for while trying to get the element ID of the grid view. How can I get the client ID of the gridview, from the web browser it is showing as --> id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView5"

```
function Validate() {
var GridID = document.getElementById('<%= GridView5.ClientID %>');

alert(GridID);
```

}

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView5" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView5_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns = "False"  HorizontalAlign="Center">
```

What am I doing that's wrong?

Comment: The `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView5` indicates that you're using autogenerated client ID. If you want to only see `GridView5` part, put `ClientIDMode="Static"` on that gridview.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, I tried that, and changed the javascript code to this , but I am getting this as the result --> [object HTMLTableElement], my js code -  var GridID = document.getElementById("GridView5");

Comment: `document.getElementById` gets the element specified by the `id` attribute, i.e. `<table>` element from gridview. if you just want to get control ID as string, simple `var GridID = '<%= GridView5.ClientID %>';` is enough.

Comment: No, it just returning <%= GridView5.ClientID %> this as its value, looks like I am specifying a string here.

Comment: Is this Javascript code on the aspx page or an external javascript file??

Comment: @GaganDeep, the javascript code is in the external file.

Comment: In the external js files you cannot use `<%= GridView5.ClientID %>` expression. Move the code to a code block in aspx file and check.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this,
var grid = $("[id*=GridView5]") 
or use
var grid = $("#<%=GridView5%>")
write this line in current page script
```

Answer (score 0):

As the Javascript code is in the external file, you cannot use `<%= GridView5.ClientID %>` expression.
I would suggest you to set the `GridView.ClientIDMode="Static"` and use the below code to acces gridview in external javascript file.
if this is your gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView5" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView5_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns = "False"  HorizontalAlign="Center" ClientIDMode="Static">
```

then use theblow code

```
var grid = $("#GridView5");
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the suggestion. This worked for me as my java scripts are in a separate file.

```
var tbl = document.getElementById("GridView5");
```